# How to extract number with different alphabet data from pandas serie?

Tags: python, pandas

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRW0S.jpg)

I have a dataset that contains a column called size. In that column, I have sizes in Megabytes and Kilobytes, like this, 19M, 853k. How can I extract the number and multiply Mb with nothing and divided kb by 1024 to get each value of the column or vice-versa? Or making it all bytes will do too.

The result set should be the only number. So, first, extract then multiply or division then change the data type

Comment: cau you provide example?(text or code, not image) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your column is called size. You can do the following in pandas:

```py
df["size in K"] = df["size"].apply(lambda x: x if s[-1]=='k' else f"{int(x[:-1])*1024}k")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I got the idea, but for some reason, your code is not working,

Comment: @mahiaslam I forgot that it would be string, fixed the code now, lol.